# String sort in alphabetic order in php8

Tags: php, php-8

I am trying to find first element(alphabetical order) from array string using loop without inbuilt functions in php8. My code is below but it is not working a intented. What is the error in my code?

eg: string = "This","is","my","apple";
apple need to print

```
$arraystring= array("This","is","my","apple");
$count = count($arraystring);



for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        if(strcmp($arraystring[$i], $arraystring[$j])<0){
            $temp = $arraystring[$i];
            $arraystring[$i] = $arraystring[$j];
            $arraystring[$j] = $temp;
        }
        
    }
}
```

my code not worked as intented

Comment: Why not [check out one of the excellent online tutorials](https://www.ma-no.org/en/programming/php/the-most-popular-array-sorting-algorithms-in-php)? Your code looks like a lot like the BubbleSort algorithm.

Comment: Your inner loop needs to start at `$j = $i+1` because all previous entries have already been sorted, and you don't need to compare an item with itself.

Comment: You probably need to set a bit and keep sorting until all values are 0. Your first outer loop puts 'my' into the first position, then never checks it again. See https://3v4l.org/JFkdc to see what's being compared

Comment: I checked your code and it is almost right. All you need to do is change `$j = 1;` to `$j = 0;` and you're done. Note that you're sorting is case sensitive. See; https://3v4l.org/Z5PZF

Comment: I would probably guess you could use [`ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to [achieve this](https://3v4l.org/TS1tX). This would support more complex checks if you use `str_split` on the substring, too.